# Linux 3.2 /dev/shm performance variable?

Tags: linux, performance, fwrite

I'm using `/dev/shm` tmpfs for writing lots of temporary files.

A set of 8-10 files/second, with each set containing files which range from 70kB .. 750kB.  The file sets are all approximately the same sizes and arrive to be written regularly about once per second.

The code which writes these files is python calling a library which uses `fwrite()` to do the writing.

When the application starts, the write times take from 30 to over 400ms.  Usually it's the largest (700k) files which can take 400ms to write but then it varies.

Here is an example of a set of 8, given in ms: 42,30,320,76,66,72,102,440.

It seems that the standard deviation of writing to `/dev/shm` is quite large.

After the application runs for a couple of minutes, the time to write plummets and the variance is much smaller (e.g. 7,8,15,23,24,32,51,71) - this behavior is stable and I have run the application for several hours.

There are no other applications of consequence running concurrently and there is plenty of room on `/dev/shm`.

*It seems that the Linux kernel is dynamically adjusting to the application's use of* `/dev/shm`.  **My question is: is my suspicion about the linux kernel correct?** If so, is there any way to configure or notify the kernel ahead of time to use the desired behavior when my application starts? (faster writes to `/dev/shm`)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

```
$ uname -a
Linux devsb02 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 
x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ls -l /dev/shm
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Aug 23 12:19 /dev/shm -> /run/shm
$ mount
....
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

Comment: Sounds like room for `/dev/shm` content is being created by evicting cache contents. If this is the case, you can cause it to happen sooner (by not just allocating but filling as much space as you intend to use)... but front-loading the delay is not the same as avoiding it.

Comment: Try increasing the `nice` value and `RT` priority of your application.